# Get text to display if value is blank ruby 4 undefined method `first_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

im a newbie to rails so please be paitent

currently this is my show page for houses in my views folder

```
.wrapper_with_padding
 #house.show
    %h1= @house.title
    %p= number_to_currency(@house.price, :unit => "£")
    %p= simple_format(@house.description)
    Occupied: #{@house.occupied}
    %br/
    Tenant: #{@house.tenant.first_name} #{@house.tenant.last_name}
```

It displays fine when the db holds a value for tenant_id in the HOUSES model, but when the tenant id is nil for a HOUSE records i get the error below.

Showing C:/Sites/landlord2/app/views/houses/show.html.haml where line #8 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass.

In show is there anyway to change

```
Tenant: #{@house.tenant.first_name} #{@house.tenant.last_name}
```

so it can display some text if the tenant_id is blank?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay, you can just ask `if @house.tenant.present?`, and if not display the desired text, like the following code:

```
.wrapper_with_padding
 #house.show
    %h1= @house.title
    %p= number_to_currency(@house.price, :unit => "£")
    %p= simple_format(@house.description)
    Occupied: #{@house.occupied}
    %br/
    -if @house.tenant.present?
      Tenant: #{@house.tenant.first_name} #{@house.tenant.last_name}
    -else
      %p= 'Text to display if tenant is blank'
```

Comment: can i ask how to get this working on my index page? at the moment i have %p.tenant_id= @house.tenant.first_name

Comment: You has the same issue on index page?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not a big fan of filling up the view with templating logic.

This would probably be a good place to use a helper method.

In your house_helper.rb file, try making a `current_tenant` method that looks something like this.

```
  def current_tenant(house)
    if house.tenant 
      "#{house.tenant.first_name} #{house.tenant.last_name}"
    else
      "Vacant"
    end
  end
```

Also, something like displaying a tenant's full name may be something you're doing a lot. Thus, it may be good to add a `full_name` method on your tenant model so that you can reuse it.

```
  class Tenant
    ...
    def full_name
      "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
    ...
  end
```

That way, you can clean up the helper method to something as simple as:

```
  def current_tenant(house)
    return "Vacant" unless house.tenant 

    house.tenant.full_name
  end
```

And your view gets cleaned up as well to:

```
.wrapper_with_padding
 #house.show
    %h1= @house.title
    %p= number_to_currency(@house.price, :unit => "£")
    %p= simple_format(@house.description)
    Occupied: #{@house.occupied}
    %br/
    Tenant: #{current_tenant(@house)}
```